# In GTK, how do I change the localized language text on the UI while it's running?

Tags: linux, internationalization, gtk

In Linux, is it possible to change the UI language on the fly which is created using GTK? I have a application which needs to change UI language on the fly.

Comment: If you're asking about a particular GUI toolkit, you should mention that in the title and question.  "Linux" is vague.

Comment: This question makes no sense.  What do you mean by 'UI language'?

Comment: @Omnifarious: It is like on first launch of application, strings that appear on UI will be of English, then after that if user wants to change to other language(say Arabic) without changing system language. This kind of feature is supported in windows as well as Mac application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to either destroy all your widgets and rebuild them with the new locale setting, or manually change all the strings to their translated equivalents. It is best to do this with gettext.

Many applications choose not to offer a setting for the UI language inside the application. Instead, they just follow the system language setting.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion. That means it is not possible to  change UI strings on the fly.

Comment: Not possible to change UI strings on the fly is incorrect.  Please see ptomato's response and my example below to show how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It is certainly possible, you just have to put a little work into it.

As an example, if you are using c#, you would first need to ensure all translatable items are included in a Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString function. A typical Label, would look like this:

```
Gtk.Label label1 = new Gtk.Label(Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("Monkey Juice"));
Gtk.Label label2 = new Gtk.Label(Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("Squirrel Love"));
```

When you do this, as long as you have the proper translation file (.po files) you will have the application startup in the current locale.  Now, if you want to change the locale from within the application, you just need to have a function that does this:

```
void ChangeToJapanese() {
     System.Globalization.CultureInfo ci = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(" ja_JP");
     System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = ci;
     label1.Text = Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("Monkey Juice");
     label2.Text = Mono.Unix.Catalog.GetString("Squirrel Love");
}
```

Now, your application should change so your labels would show 猿ジュース and リスの愛.

Comment: This is what I meant by "manually change all the strings to their translated equivalents."

Comment: Yes, That is what I suspected.  The person that asked the question still seemed to think you can't do it "on-the-fly", but in fact the method you suggested and I have shown example code for would do exactly what he wants.

Answer (score 1):

I changed the language on the fly, following these steps:

1. Create a `.po` file containing key-value pairs for the translations:

   msgid "Yes"
   msgstr "Ja"
2. Use `msgfmt` in order to obtain a `.mo` file, which must be moved into the corresponing `LC_MESSAGES` folder of the locale (e.g. `/usr/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES`):

   msgfmt myapp.po - o myapp.mo
3. Bind this file to the application:

   ```
   #define ENABLE_NLS

   #ifdef ENABLE_NLS


       #include <libintl.h>
               #include <locale.h>
               #define PACKAGE_LOCALE_DIR "/usr/share/locale"

               // "myapp" is the mo file name in LOCALE
               #define GETTEXT_PACKAGE    "myapp"

               #  undef _
               #  define _(String) dgettext (GETTEXT_PACKAGE, String)
               #  ifdef gettext_noop
               #    define N_(String) gettext_noop (String)
               #  else
               #    define N_(String) (String)
               #  endif

   #else
   #  define textdomain(String) (String)
   #  define gettext(String) (String)
   #  define dgettext(Domain,Message) (Message)
   #  define dcgettext(Domain,Message,Type) (Message)
   #  define bindtextdomain(Domain,Directory) (Domain)
   #  define _(String) (String)
   #  define N_(String) (String)
   #endif
   ```
4. Whenever the language must be changed, call these methods:

   ```
   if(setlocale(LC_ALL, language)==NULL)
   {
       printf("--> changeLAnguage: ERROR !!!\r\n");
       return false;
   }

   setenv("LANGUAGE", language, true);
   setenv("LANG", language, true);
   setenv("LC_ALL", language, true);
   setenv("LC_MESSAGES", language, true);
   setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
   ```
5. Set the text of the labels by using the `msgids` in the `.po` file:

   ```
   SetTextOfLabel("label1", _(MSG_ID_1));
   ```

   For example,

   ```
   gtk_label_set_text(GTK_LABEL(widget),str);
   ```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can use NAppGUI, that supports runtime translations in Windows (WinAPI), macOS (Cocoa) and Linux (Gtk).

http://nappgui.com/es/demo/products.html#h4.5