# Reload all text of glade interface (Gtk::Builder) when change language in gtkmm

Tags: c++, gettext, gtkmm, glade

I use gtkmm, glade (Gtk::Builder) and gettext. When users select other
language in the program, I have to restart the process to reload all interfaces.

Is there any way to reload text of glade interface with gettext and C++ ?

Comment: There is no way to do it automatically. You can either restart the process, or manually change all the strings. Many programs just follow the system language setting for that reason. I believe this is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939959

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In GTK, how do I change the localized language text on the UI while it's running?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3939959/in-gtk-how-do-i-change-the-localized-language-text-on-the-ui-while-its-running)